# Grouping keys and values with Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have some data. numeric key and numeric value:

```
[
        (468793398, 672),
        (468793398, 2464),
        (521683990, 131152)
]
```

I need to group keys and values like this:

```
[
    (468793398, 3136), 
    (521683990, 131152)
]
```

The key should be unique and values with the same key should be
incremented to each other.

Please help me to write a python code to solve this problem. It looks simple, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```py
lst = [(468793398, 672), (468793398, 2464), (521683990, 131152)]

out = {}
for k, v in lst:
    out[k] = out.get(k, 0) + v

print(list(out.items()))
```

Prints:

```
[(468793398, 3136), (521683990, 131152)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` (and `operator.itemgetter`) for this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [
    (468793398, 672),
    (468793398, 2464),
    (521683990, 131152)
]

result = [
    (key, sum(map(itemgetter(1), group))) 
    for key, group in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0))
]
```